# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE XhrIoPool is not an constructor

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, webpack

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase_webchannel_wrapper__.XhrIoPool is not a constructor
    at new WebChannelConnection (http://localhost :8100/build/vendor.js:155972:21)
    at BrowserPlatform.loadConnection (http ://localhost: 8100/build/vendor.js:155873:32)
    at FirestoreClient.initializeRest (http ://localhost:8 100/build/vendor.js:158035:14)
    at http://loc alhost :8100/build/vendor.js:157926:54
    at t.invoke (http ://localhos t:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://loca lhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5445:33)
    at t.invoke (http ://local ost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localho st:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http ://localhost:81 00/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
    at t.invokeTask (http: //localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This thread may have some useful pointers. If anyone can find any clues based on this thread please share: 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1606

Comment: I never found how to fix it, i just reinstalled the entire environment

Comment: How did you "reinstall the entire environment"? What happened after you did the reinstal?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be related to the wrong version of @firebase/channel-wrapper
See this[github issue comment](https://github.com/Tim1023/react-scheduler-firebase/issues/3#issuecomment-496862738)

The fix:

```sh
npm uninstall @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.2.20;
npm install @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.2.7;
npm start;
```